# ESlint and Puppeteer, disable eslint for specific functions

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, eslint

I'm using [`puppeteer`](https://pptr.dev/) and I have `eslint` in my project.
I'm getting errors like the following:

```
211:67  error  '$' is not defined          no-undef
```

because in my code I use things like `#evaluate()`:

```js
await page.evaluate(async (customVariable) => {
   $("...").text();
   // ...
});
```

so is there a possibility to globally disable `eslint` for a specific function name (`evaluate` in my case)?
It would be nice if it's possible to do that from the global configuration (`.eslintrc.js` file, in my case).

Thanks

Comment: A more appropriate solution would be to define `$` as a global variable for eslint https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals  You can do that either at the top of the file or in the .eslintrc.js file (that link shows both examples)

Comment: Hi, thank you @MichaelS. It seems a good idea, I'm gonna use it if there are not alternatives! Thanks

Comment: you can also do it for the file with `/* global $ */`, or add `// eslint-disable-next-line` to the line before to completely disable eslint for the one line.  Alternately, you could do `var $ = window.$;` or just `window.$("...").text()` - eslint is already aware of "window" as a global value.  All of these would fix the eslint error.